# Delete non-integer digits and symbols from mysql column

Tags: mysql

In a 'items' table , i have a column name 'prices'.
It contains values like

> $ 2.5 USD
>
> $ 84.2 USD

I want to remove $ and USD. 'prices' column should look like

> 2.5
>
> 84.2

Comment: use [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). Eg `REPLACE(REPLACE(prices, '$', ''), 'USD', '')`

Comment: @JohnWoo And maybe call `TRIM` as well to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen totally agree on that.

Comment: Thank you, i tried this select REPLACE(REPLACE('$ 2.5 USD','$',''),'USD', '');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this `update`

```
update items set prices= REPLACE(REPLACE(prices,'$',''),'USD', '');
```